# ros navigation driving principle

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I have one question.

As a mobile robot, I know about global plans and local plans.

How can I check whether the mobile robot is going correctly or not about the plan?

The environment is indoor, IMU, lidar, RGB-D.

I would appreciate it if you let me know the information.

If you let us know, you will be rich.

Please. ㅠㅠ

Thanks for reading.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347297/ros-navigation-driving-principle/) by [mywjdp@naver.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/52779/mywjdp@naver.com/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How can I check whether the mobile robot is going correctly or not about the plan?

That is extremely use-case specific and we cannot possibly tell you. If your robot has successfully created a plan and the controller is successfully moving the robot, why would you expect that the robot wouldn't be "going correctly about the plan"?

Certainly, there's a variety of ways that navigation may be suboptimal and you may want to detect such events, but again, very use-case specific we cannot answer.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mywjdp@naver.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/52779/mywjdp@naver.com/) on 2020-03-23**:
How do you do it in general?
If the global plan is a straight line, you need to know if the robot is going straight, should it go straight, and if there's a little off-the-road, shouldn't there be a way to get back to the global plan?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-24**:
Anywhere the `tfBuffer_` variable is used to lookup transformations.